# Getting an error in response Header

Tags: jmeter

We are doing API testing. For one API (in the middle) we need one token code which is generating in redirect URL of one web application flow. Since we are doing performance testing so I am adding the manual flow also in my script. The manual flow includes:

1. Launch
2. Login
3. Click on complete option

Then after clicking it is showing success popup for 2 sec then page is redirecting to one google url which is having that access token code. I have done all the correlations and script for the flow but in my script the redirect URL in location field of response header is not coming correctly. I am getting below wrong redirect URL:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 07:42:23 GMT Content-Type:
>   text/html;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
>   includeSubDomains Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Pragma: no-cache X-XSS-Protection: 1;
>   mode=block Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Location:
>   https://google.com#error_description=Unexpected+Runtime+Authn+Adapter+Integration+Problem.&state=af0ifjsldkj&error=server_error

Expected Response Header:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2019 13:16:52 GMT Content-Type:
>   text/html;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
>   includeSubDomains Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Pragma: no-cache X-XSS-Protection: 1;
>   mode=block Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Location:
>   https://google.com#code=XisAQ92nQU75ypPxcDt5mMYkzTVwN9SYZcZFRF18&id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InhsMTZCRHh3NTdKTi0zUHR2cm15QS16V1RnTSJ9.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.s2WVaMvMlKkr7M_o46Sk7dt6YaUKdUNyNl8XEKBYCsnA4OWMK6TS5HCH5Z31zN-_9QaLpDXp68dsvqfv-OH4Zj0r9sqfNwFGQ8ksKhoPxUQw_runiQlbidS9n9EZa7nPexJLAwxfthQR9E7GZQU4E3vG8eStOot8yQP8-YIN-BLsIQFCw5XrPFQRojEW9r6JpLYaVy2IaAUWlXk6wrydS6yo3rQsOBDa0NVQ07xemyk1SmQ4ee3SVbsRpGTbZlQSKNzpa3gJsJDPpF7MQVPedzdrAzsHjOERk9sEDOYeHskhLr5xrZ_glp_mf84OBlvxd21b7G0kLU1BXN9Uz9XCFA&state=af0ifjsldkj

Could you please help me to fix this issue.